# Connect WebService Restful in asp.net to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new here so sorry if I do not explain myself well.

I have a basic asp.net RESTful API which returns 2 contacts, I "consume it" from an Android project, my question is if I can or how to connect the webservice to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Database I have in another machine.

**Should I make the connection in the ContactRepository as a simply connection or I need to make something different?**

ContactRepository:

```
namespace PruebaRestful.Services
{
    public class ContactRepository
    {
        public Contact[] GetAllContacts()
        {
            return new Contact[]
            {
            new Contact
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Glenn Block"
            },
            new Contact
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Dan Roth"
            }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

ContactController:

```
namespace PruebaRestful.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : ApiController
    {
        private ContactRepository contactRepository;

        public ContactController()
        {
            this.contactRepository = new ContactRepository();
        }

        
        public Contact[] Get()
        {
            return contactRepository.GetAllContacts();        
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to all and please if I need to write something more tell me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) i.e. its generally as simple as having the ContactController  accept a connection object in the constructor.  Normally you would use the IConnection interface as opposed to a concrete connection class to allow you to mock it out for testing.

```
namespace PruebaRestful.Services
{
    public class ContactRepository
    {
        private IConnection _connection;

        public ContactRepository(IConnection connection)
        {
            _connection = connection;
        }

        public Contact[] GetAllContacts()
        {
            return new Contact[]
            {
            new Contact
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Glenn Block"
            },
            new Contact
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Dan Roth"
            }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

To see more how to do it in Asp.Net see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can do it in any way (ADO.net or any other ORM).

In your scenario, you could apply the dependency inversion principle.

> The higher level module should not depend on lower level abstractions

In your case, the consumer should not be aware about from where the data is being provided. All you need is to change `GetAllContacts` to read data from db using the ORM.

```
public class DbConnection: IConnection 
{
    // Code for managing DB Connection and data querying
}

public class ContactRepository: IContactRepository
{
    private IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    public ContactRepository(IConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection= dbConnection;
    }

    public Contact[] GetAllContacts()
    {
         // Add code to read from DB here
    }
}

public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    private IContactRepository _contactRepository;

    public ContactController()
    {
        _contactRepository = <using any DI container resolve dependency with ContactRepository>;
    }


    public Contact[] Get()
    {
        return _contactRepository.GetAllContacts();        
    }
}
```